# Apache ProxyPass doesn't seem to be proxying content from remote host

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to create a proxy at a URL on my "master" site to a remote site, "east", but I get stuck in a redirection loop. This isn't the behaviour I was expecting - I understood ProxyPass would rewrite the content to the URL, but I think it's acting as if it's redirecting to the "master" host.

The configuration file applied is pretty straightforward:

```
user@master:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled# cat multisite_proxy.conf
<Location /prod_east>
        ProxyPass http://east.domain.com/prod_east
        ProxyPassReverse http://east.domain.com/prod_east
</Location>
```

using cURL, my output is as:

```
user@master:~# curl -IL https://master.domain.com/prod_east/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 22:58:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Location: https://master.domain.com//prod_east/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

...

curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

The Apache logs on east are showing cURL's requests.

If I browse `http://east.domain.com/prod_east` I get redirected to an application's login page (which I expect). Examining that with cURL, I see:

```
user@master:~# curl -IL http://east.domain.com/prod_east
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 23:17:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Location: https://east.domain.com//prod_east
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 23:17:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://east.domain.com/prod_east/subpath/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 23:17:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Cookie
Cache-Control: no-cache
**Location: /prod_east/subpath/login.py?_origtarget=index.py**
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The last Location: entry has me wondering: It's telling the client to redirect to `/prod_east/`, but I expect that to be requested from `east.domain.com` because of the ProxyPass rules.

The Proxy module is enabled, as is the rewrite module.

Any help? I'm clearly not understanding something here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that the "east" site was forcing a redirection to HTTPS, and Apache wasn't configured to proxy TLS content. After enabling SSLProxy on "master", and updating `multisite_proxy.conf` to refer to https (thus skipping the HTTP->HTTPS redirection), this is now working.